# redirect to URL and bring errors in PHP?

Tags: php, redirect, verification

I suspected this wouldn't work, and it didn't - but I can't seem to find a similar question anywhere so here we go. I had a if else statement that checked to see if they couldn't log in it would show why (errors), and if there were, they would be echoed out, and otherwise, $_SESSION would be assigned a user id (having already been started beforehand) that was retrieved from a variable that equates to a function which queries the mySQL db.  and the page would redirect to an account page, as so:

```
if (!empty($errors)) {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error . '<br />'; .
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
    header('Location: you/default.php');
    exit();
}
```

The problem is this login form is in a dropdown menu on the homepage (rather than being a page in it's own right), and if they can't log in (incorrect password, an unfilled field, etc), I want to redirect to the login.php page and then display the errors, so I tried adding `header('Location: login.php');` before the foreach statement, but it just redirected to login.php, like I expected, and didn't bring the errors along with it.

I suspect this may be a job for AJAX or something other than PHP... ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out a way to do this myself. In my case if there were errors (`if (!empty($errors))`), I applied them to the `$_SESSION` superglobal as `$_SESSION['errors']`.

It then redirects the page to `login.php` where a simple if statement echos them out there:

```
    if (isset($_SESSION['lqerrors'])) {
    $lqerrors = $_SESSION['lqerrors'];
        foreach ($lqerrors as $lqerror) {
            echo $lqerror, '<br />'; 
        }
    unset($lqerrors,$lqerror,$_SESSION['lqerrors']);
}
```

Easy!

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your session before adding variables to it. Also make sure nothing has been output before this code.

```
if (!empty($errors)) {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error . '<br />'; // notice i've replaced the comma in your code with a colon.
    }
} else {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
    header('Location: you/default.php');
    exit();
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.security.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

**Also**, in every other page that needs to access the session, you'll have to call session_start(); before outputing anything.

Comment: sorry, poor wording on my part - a session was started much earlier in an initialize file, and I'm told that I don't need to declare it again. Still doesn't solve my problem however.

Comment: Ok, so what exactly is not working? does it just not redirect, throw any errors?

Comment: if you're getting a parse error, remove the comma between $error and <br>? I don't know if that was just a typo on your question here or if it's in your code too.

Comment: I've reworded my question- if they cannot log in, I want to redirect to another page (login.php) and show those errors to them. I hope this makes sense?

Comment: I guess I'm still not clear as to what your current result is. Is it throwing any errors, does it just stay on the page? or what happens? Are you sure your code is executing? e.g. have you tried putting die('abc') inside of your if statement as a way to debug it?

Comment: The code works fine, there are no errors there. The errors I'm trying to convey are failures in the login verification process such as 'Wrong password', 'No such account exists', 'All fields must be filled'.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pass the errors along to your new page. You could do something like:

```
header('Location: login.php?error[]="'.$error1.'"&error[]="'.$error2.'");
```

Of course, then you'll have to check for these in login.php :)